# Showing different layout of dialogbox with API level 28

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-studio-2.0

Showing different layout of dialog box with the same code. Works fine with API level from 27 to lower but once run with API 28, it is not display correctly. I figure out is the problem of theme using,I using "theme.dialog" as my theme. Anyone know what happen to the theme.dialog in API 28?

[layout of API28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to6vo.png)
   [layout of API24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfCvI.png)

Comment: I have this issue with p (android 9) while we do dialog.show() it does not displayed completely(only page is locked).If the issues is from the layout , how to change theme of Dialog for android 9

Comment: There is a parent name side with the style name of the theme, just change the parent name to another Theme.

Comment: Is it possible for you to tell me with more details ?